# WSUS: Error: Connection Error

Tags: windows-server-2008, wsus

I am running WSUS services on Windows 2008 R2 Standard. Since 3-4 weeks I am getting below error and memory utilization is high too. Can you please help me to solve this, Let me know if I need to share more information on this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar has been [reported](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/configurationmgr/2017/08/18/high-cpuhigh-memory-in-wsus-following-update-tuesdays/) to be caused by the Windows 10 1607 updates, so it's possible that the 1709 *Fall Creators* Update might cause this too. Here's short version of the similarities & solution:

> The symptoms include
>
> - High memory in the w3wp.exe process hosting the WsusPool – customers have reported memory usage approach 24GB
>
> **Cause**
>
> These updates have large metadata payloads for the dependent (child) packages because they roll up a large number of binaries. Windows 10, versions 1507 (Windows 10 RTM) and 1511 updates can also cause this, though to a lesser extent. Windows 10, version 1703 is still recent enough that the metadata is not that large yet (but will continue to grow).
>
> **Solution**
>
> A WSUS update is now available that includes improvements for update metadata processing. This update should be applied to all WSUS servers in your environment.
>
> - Windows Server 2016  ([KB4039396](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4039396)).
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 ([KB4039871](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4039871))
> - Windows Server 2012 ([KB4039873](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4039873))
> - WSUS 3.0 SP2 ([KB4039929](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4039929))

On your Windows Server 2008 R2 you should already have WSUS 3.0 SP2 installed; check whether [KB4039929](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4039929) is already installed and install if needed. If this didn't help you could...

**Increase the ASP.NET timeout**. This shortened version omits making the backups:

1. `\Program Files\Update Services\WebServices\ClientWebService\Web.Config`
2. Modify `httpRunTime` by adding an `executionTimeout` attribute:

   ```
   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" executionTimeout="3600" />
   ```
3. From an elevated command prompt, run `IISReset` to restart IIS.